# How to Print PDF as image similar to Acrobat setting "Print as Image" in Java?

Tags: java, pdf, printing, pdfbox

I'm looking for a solution in Java to print PDF files as Images similar to a setting in Acrobat "Print as Image" so that Spool file size is reduced. Currently, I'm using Apache Pdfbox.

Here is my print method-

```
public static boolean print(PDDocument document, String printerName) throws PrinterException {
    PrintService printService = findPrintService(printerName);
    if (printService == null) {
        LOGGER.error("Printer Could Not be Found or initialized");
        try {
            document.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("PDF FDocument could not be closed");
        }
        return false;
    }
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PDFPageable pageablePDF = new PDFPageable(document);
    job.setPageable(pageablePDF);
    job.setPrintService(printService);
    job.print();
    try {
        document.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("PDF FDocument could not be closed");
    }
    LOGGER.info("File is successfully sent to a printer {}", printerName);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: try setting a specific dpi (e.g. 600) in the  PDFPageable constructor, is that what you mean?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr
No I'm specifically looking for a solution which will ensure that there are no layers in PDF and every page in PDF is rendered as an Image so that there are no issues like font not being available & very large EMF Spool file.

Comment: Passing dpi means that the PDF is first converted to image and then printed.